# How to deploy .Net application to heroku

Tags: .net, heroku, web-deployment

I do not see much help when it comes to deploying .Net app to Heroku.

So, how to deploy .Net application to Heroku?

Answer (score 24):

This is demo app on asp.net 5 beta7 https://github.com/jincod/AspNet5DemoApp. Using buildpack forked from heroku/dotnet-buildpack.

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try running ASP.Net & .Net console applications using the open source Mono framework.  There is a buildpack to deploy these apps for you on Heroku at:

https://github.com/friism/heroku-buildpack-mono

To deploy your app on Heroku with this buildpack, install the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and run the following commands in the root of your project folder

- `heroku create`
- `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/friism/heroku-buildpack-mono/`
- `git push heroku master`

Also read [Running .Net on Heroku](http://friism.com/running-net-on-heroku) for more details and some limitations